# reuse of temp table getting more time to execute

Tags: sql-server-2008, temporary-tables

i'm creating temp table as,

```
SELECT 
    T.CD,
    T.OBJECT_CD,
    T.PRICE 
    INTO #TEMP FROM TABLE_NAME T
```

**EDIT : ADDED CLUSTERED INDEX TO TEMP TABLE**

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Temp_OBJECT_CD
    ON #Temp (OBJECT_CD);
```

and using this table `#TEMP` two times in another query to get results as,

```
SELECT MAX(T1.PRICE),
        MIN(T1.PRICE),
        MAX(T2.PRICE),
        MIN(T2.PRICE)
        FROM PP INNER JOIN #TEMP T1 ON T1.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD
        INNER JOIN #TEMP T2 ON T2.CD = PP.CD AND T2.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD
```

but the query is taking more time to execute. when i remove any one of `T1` or `T2` from `JOIN` the query retrieves result instantly. what could be the reason?

Comment: Posting the execution plans may help us to help you.

Comment: Also please, inform about your PP table (structure, indexes, ...)

Comment: Are the number of rows in the temp table very different between the two calls?

Comment: @JonSeigel: No, temp table rows do not vary

Comment: Reuse is not a good title. To me that is clear the table and use it again.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a second column to the clustered index statement, make it be

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Temp_OBJECT_CD ON #Temp (OBJECT_CD, CD)
```

That may help, depending on how many CD's there are to OBJECT_CD's.

Comment: I don't think that will help performance and it breaks the current definition of a PK.  It would probably even slow down the T1 join.  Right now the T1 join can stop when it finds a hit.  And on T2 when it find a hit then it just need to examine the value of  CD in that row only.

Comment: Clustered indexes are not primary keys.  Primary keys (whether natural, surrogate, single or composite) are used to uniquely identify a row of data.  Clustered Indexes are how you want the data to be physically sorted on disk.  I don't know if my recommendation was even used, the OP hasn't updated this question since 2014 so we may never know.  But having a clustered index specified on the #TEMP has to be better than a heap.  The server has an index to work from and better statistics to make better join decisions.

Comment: Fair enough..  +1

Answer (score 0):

Remove the join is going to be faster.  Less rows and less complexity.

```
SELECT MAX(T1.PRICE), MIN(T1.PRICE),
       MAX(T2.PRICE), MIN(T2.PRICE)
  FROM PP 
  JOIN #TEMP T1 ON T1.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD
  JOIN #TEMP T2 ON T2.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD AND T2.CD = PP.CD
```

To reduce fragmentation and faster insert use

```
SELECT 
    T.CD,
    T.OBJECT_CD,
    T.PRICE 
    INTO #TEMP FROM TABLE_NAME T 
    ORDER BY T.OBJECT_CD
```

For sure you should have an index on PP.OBJECT_CD
Make sure it is not fragmented

Start with the above and examine (and post) the query plan

Consider an index on #TEMP.price but that is going to slow down the insert

**More important why are you even using #TEMP in the first place?**

```
SELECT MAX(T1.PRICE), MIN(T1.PRICE),
       MAX(T2.PRICE), MIN(T2.PRICE)
  FROM PP 
  JOIN TABLE_NAME T1 ON T1.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD
  JOIN TABLE_NAME T2 ON T2.OBJECT_CD = PP.OBJECT_CD AND T2.CD = PP.CD
```

Make sure the join columns are indexed.  Declare PK and or unique if that is the case.  If it is PK/unique then the join can stop when it finds a hit.